# Can't receive text on Vodafone Indian number abroad

Tags: cellphones

I have an Indian Vodafone number and I am unable to receive any text Messages on it, I can receive calls thou. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Contact Vodafone India customer service.

Comment: It should have an active plan. Without an active plan (even if the cheapest one), you get personal texts but not bank otp. That's been my experience. If you are not getting even after an active plan, you should contact customer care.